# How to use Elementor global Colors in Custom CSS?

Tags: html, css, elementor

In Elementor I define global colors:

[image: global colors]

When I use custom CSS classes I want tho use these colors in my global css e.g. style.css of my child theme.

I want to define a global button class which I can use anywhere such that I only have to define a button once like this:

```
/* Button-Style test-btn-bg */
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button {fill: var( --e-global-color-ea5eb24 );}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button {color: var( --e-global-color-ea5eb24 );}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button {background-color: var( --mgred );}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button {border-style: solid;}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button {border-color: var( --e-global-color-f562e12 );}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button {border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button:hover {color: var( --e-global-color-f562e12 );}
.test-btn-bg .elementor-button:hover {background-color: var( --e-global-color-f562e12 );
}
```

Now I would use the `test-btn-bg` class as a custom css and add this class to a button. That would give me the advantage that I only have to define button style once an have them all set.

**How do I use the global colors in my css class? Where do I have to define the color variables for the CSS to make it work?**